# How can I tell whether my friend has been cheating?

Tags: terraria

My friend claims he used to play Terraria in his previous so-call 'hardmode' account, but it seems as if he's mastered the game having very much the best of all items. Being very hard to believe as I got him the game however he claims it to be a file of his old player from his friends computer.

That is **still** believable, but just look at the image below:

[image]

If you do notice his buff icon has an ironskin potion and swiftness potion stacking up to 9999 hours, could anyone **confirm**, if this is normal?

Comment: By the way, I looked through his perspective through Skype.

Comment: Not normal, probably edited the save.

Comment: easy on the downvotes guys. english is hard.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no way your friend got those buffs legitimately. The max duration for the Ironskin buff is 5 minutes and Swiftness buff is 4 minutes.

Buffs also do not stack in effect or duration.

Your friend cheated those buffs.

Sources:

[Terraria Wiki Buffs](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Buffs)

[Terraria Wiki Potions (Notes)](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Potions#Notes)

Comment: Oh yeah, but my friend claims it's a glitch. Is that believable?

Comment: @elfinlocks2151 No.

Comment: Nah, your friend is a cheater. There's no (known) [glitch](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Known_Bugs_And_Glitches) that does that

Comment: Also, isn't exploitation of a glitch another form of cheating?

Comment: @EtherDragon Possibly, but that's certainly more controversial than save editing.